# Is there a downside to using a deprecated version of the ERC20 ABI?

Tags: solidity, abi

I am aware there is deprecated keyword "constant" present in old versions of Solidity ABI for ERC20. Is this still just as good as the latest versions, or should I update asap? On the other hand, is there an advantage to using the old version, in terms of compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be okay. The ABI's only role is to tell you how to interact with a contract, aka, the name of the functions you can call and what kind parameters you should pass.

If the "deprecated" version of the ABI has the same function names and parameter types, then you can use it